# What is this soft, blue ring from my shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

Note- we took apart the shower pan and whoever installed it used parts for the kitchen sink such as a flexible hose... Thanks everyone for your help, and you were right/ it was a bad install...

While i was plunging out a shower in Spain, blue thing came out of the shower outlet.

It looks a bit melted, I did use drain cleaner on the shower a few times. There are some supicious marks on it that might indicate it was under compression and some old sand on it that has engrooved a bit. It looks stretched and melted. But since its melted looking I cannot tell for sure.

Is it possible this ring connects something and came loose or is this more like a situation where someone dropped something in there on accident? note that the measuring stick in the picture is in metric

[image: pic 1]

[image: flipped]

[image]

I googled for blue plumbing rings and only saw a blue product in image below, but not sure if it's this, its blue and maybe the wrong size. [image] (from spanish website, european measurements)

Comment: Was this a stiff blockage where you were exerting large amounts of pressure? It's barely worth mentioning, but I suppose that your blue part could have been part of a slip joint between a pipe blockage and your plunger. In the US you would never find a shower plumbed with slip joints, but I don't know what's done in Spain.

Answer (score 1):

Shower pan drains are often installed by setting the pan over a pipe stub and then inserting a seal between the pipe and the pan drain cup. This could be that. They're usually more robust, larger black rubber rings, though. See "Compression Seal" in this diagram:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wingtite.com%2Fpages%2Fexisting-drain-removal&psig=AOvVaw0UI9naUXkBM4hPTHxkf6kt&ust=1686229637285000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCLCWmoedsf8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAa)</sub>

Or it could be completely unrelated to the plumbing.

I would gently pop the drain grille out (removing any screws present first) and have a look for such a seal. If it's missing, seek a new replacement part before using the shower again.

Comment: hole diamer is only about 2-3cm, could it still be that?

Comment: I noticed that. It's unlikely, but worth a check if it's not too much trouble with your particular shower.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a guess:  It is the blue plumbing part that you included in your question, it was dropped into the drain accidentally by the person who installed the drain or the shower, and left there where it has been rotting ever since, hence its current condition and your need to repeatedly use chemical and mechanical drain cleaners on the shower.

Normally, if you have someone who sheds a lot of long hair and uses a lot of conditioner, you'll need to treat your drain once every three to five years.  Any common treatment should be effective, you should not have to do it repeatedly.  If you don't have such a person, you should never have to do this.

Comment: could be, it kind of looks like it was cut with a knife but not all the way through, and it looks like it was under compression at some point. could have just fallen in during install.. i should take a peek inside if i can i guess :-(